# Converting 64 bit hash to integer in range

Tags: java, hash, long-integer, murmurhash

I'm trying to hash a string to a location in a byte array of length n. I am using the following implementation of the `Murmur` hash function:

https://github.com/tnm/murmurhash-java/blob/master/src/main/java/ie/ucd/murmur/MurmurHash.java

in order to obtain 64 bit `long` hashes of the form:

```
-5399126022617539698
-6327203148514768842
2105496855350268822
8607374935780018902
-5250032588095247395
552173613799679926
5079571629675690815
```

How can I now convert this long to an integer in the range of `0 - byte_array.length-1`?

Comment: by using the `%` modulo operator?

Comment: what is the value I am `%` with?

Comment: `byte_array.length`.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer @luk2302.  Otherwise I can.